# How to bundle a third party jar in maven?

Tags: java, maven, jar

I would like to bundle tibjms.jar and javax.jms-api-2.0.jar into a single bundle using maven bundle plugin. Since the tibjms.jar is not in the maven repos I first added it to my local repo:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/home/riyafa/Documents/Workspace/Support/NNINSURANCESUB-17/tibco/libs/jms-2.0.jar -DgroupId=com.tibco -DartifactId=tibjms -Dversion=4.4.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=false
```

Then I created the following pom file and built it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.riyafa</groupId>
    <artifactId>tibco</artifactId>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <version>1</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tibco</groupId>
            <artifactId>tibjms</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Name>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-Name>
                        <Export-Package>
                            com.tibco.tibjms.*,
                            com.tibco.tibjms.naming.*,
                            com.tibco.tibjms.naming.tibjmsnaming.*,
                        </Export-Package>
                        <Import-Package>
                            *,
                            !javax.jms.*,
                        </Import-Package>

                        <Embed-Dependency>
                            javax.jms-api;scope=compile|runtime;inline=false;
                        </Embed-Dependency>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The build is successful, but I only see the javax.jms-api-2.0.jar in the generated jar:
[image]

I want to bundle both the jars. How can I achieve this when one of the jars is a thirparty jar? I have also tried adding the jar to pom file as an external library which did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't you just forget to add an `EmbedDependency` for `tibjms`? You can also embed all compile and runtime depenedencies:

```
<Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime;inline=false</Embed-Dependency>
```

Please note that `javax.jms-api` is already packaged as a bundle. If the only purpose of the `tibco` artifact is to bundle `tibjms` and `jms-api`, you could consider skipping it altogether and instead package `tibjms` as a bundle. Then you can deploy both `tibjms` and `jms-api` as separate bundles.

Comment: Thanks!! I want them to be in a single bundle because  I want the methods exposed by jms-api to be visible only to tibjms.jar as it is conflicting with another jar.